# Can Craft be used on same site as other eCommerce Solutions

Tags: installation, ecommerce

Is it possible to have a Craft installation on the same site as another ecommerce solution like OpenCart or OSCommerce?
Reason being those and some others are already linked with Sage and would like to keep the general content of the site updated using Craft.

Answer (score 1):

You *shouldn't* have any issues running multiple applications on the same host but it would be smarter to decouple the different applications and build a bridge between them.

I've never worked with OSCommerce or OpenCart so I can't speak to the specifics of what's involved in doing that but if your high-level goal is to run Craft on the same server as the other application(s), that *should* be fine.

Comment: How do you decouple and build a bridge between them?

Comment: That's a loaded question that really requires someone with knowledge of the ecommerce implementation to architect. The short answer: build a set of API endpoints to/from both applications where necessary.